# Latex - References do not appear

Tags: bibtex

I have a `latex` file which was working perfectly on another PC. I install `TexStudio` and `Miktex` on my new PC and I compile the `Latex` file. The references (are in `bib` file) do not appear and I get the error which is mentioned below.

FYI, I use this style `\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}`

**Error:**

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template.aux
I couldn't open style file model5-names.bst
---line 19 of file elsarticle-template.aux
 : \bibstyle{model5-names
 :                       }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file elsarticle-template.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The BibTeX error message is clear: BibTeX wasn't able to find the bibliography style file `model5-names`. If BibTeX doesn't have a bib style file to work with, it won't create a formatted bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the following link and save it in the same directory as my `latex` file using this name: `model5-names.bst`

```
https://wwwatlas.mpp.mpg.de/ftp/outgoing/papers/vci2016/model5-names.bst
```

Comment: A more official source is probably https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions or more specifically the `.zip` file https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip linked on that site. It contains `model5-names.bst`. I really wonder why Elsevier's example template comes with and uses its own `.bst` files when the `elsarticle` package on CTAN https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle also comes with `.bst` files...

Comment: You can accept own answer and by this inform members of site, that your question is solved.